# Python Selenium Using WebDriverWait and presence_of_element_located times out despite element being present

Tags: python, selenium, continuous-integration, integration-testing, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a test running with this in the setUp method of the class:

```
self.selenium.implicitly_wait(40)
```

And in the specific test

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.selenium, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "element_id"))
)
```

The element with that ID is a `<button>` element.

The test kept timing out at this point. But I had a hunch the element was actually there, so I added this:

```
container = self.selenium.find_element_by_id('element_id_parent')
print container.get_attribute('innerHTML')

element = WebDriverWait(self.selenium, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "element_id"))
)
```

And sure enough, the html printout shows the element with id `element_id` is there even **before** the `WebDriverWait`. So it should just find it and continue right?

Occasionally the test passes. More frequently in a local environment, almost never in the CI.

Has anyone run across this? Any solutions come to mind, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you show how the printed `innerHTML` looks like? Thanks.

Comment: I recognize this might not be the cause of your problem, however, you usually want to avoid mixing implicit and explicit waits: `http://www.aptuz.com/blog/selenium-implicit-vs-explicit-waits/`